# How to combine multiple columns into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following example table:

```
| name   | email1          | email2            | email3         | 
.................................................................
| John   | john@gmail.com  | john@hotmail.com  | john@yahoo.com |
| Jane   | jane@gmail.com  | NULL              | NULL           |
```

I need a query to combine the email columns in the way that the result would look like this, ignoring the nulls:

```
| name   | email            |
.............................
| John   | john@gmail.com   |
| John   | john@hotmail.com | 
| John   | john@yahoo.com   |
| Jane   | jane@gmail.com   |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: union all, one select per email-column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.name, v.email
from t cross join lateral
     (values (email1), (email2), (email3)) v(email)
where v.email is not null;
```

Comment: Neato! I need to start remembering lateral joins exist

Comment: @Mureinik . . . They are just like correlated subqueries that can return more than one column and more than one row (and are in the `FROM` clause).

Answer (score 0):

You can `union all` a series of queries on each email column:

```sql
SELECT name, email1
WHERE  email1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT name, email2
WHERE  email2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT name, email3
WHERE  email3 IS NOT NULL
```